# check 2 primary key in one table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table psc_Pro_ProfessorPositions(ProfessorID,PositionID,StartDate,EndDate). It have 2 primary key is ProfessorID,PositionID.

I want to check ProfessorID,PositionID not in table to insert.I wrote like this:

insert into CoreUIs.dbo.psc_Pro_ProfessorPositions
    (
        ProfessorID,PositionID,StartDate,EndDate
    )

```
select a.MaQuanLy,b.MaQuanLy,convert(smalldatetime,NgayHieuLuc),convert(smalldatetime,NgayHetHieuLuc) 

from inserted

inner join GiangVien a on a.MaGiangVien = inserted.MaGiangVien
inner join ChucVu b on b.MaChucVu = inserted.MaChucVu
where a.MaQuanLy not in (select ProfessorID  from CoreUIs.dbo.psc_Pro_ProfessorPositions)
and b.MaQuanLy not in (select PositionID  from CoreUIs.dbo.psc_Pro_ProfessorPositions)
```

But it's wrong.Can help me?Thanks all.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're doing.  Your two tables appear to have identical structures.  It would help if you showed us the SQL that you've already tried.

Comment: someone pls format the question as per stackoverflow standard... I don't have rights to do it :(

Comment: I believe `70100G07.000051|CD09CKM1| CNC102040| 90` should be `70100G07.000051|CD09CKM1| CNC102040| NULL`.. First should be NULL and second should be 90...

Comment: @Jason : I believe he want to overwrite first table with second table...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Can you please explain what `TB2` has to do with anything? It seems to me like the results you want rely solely on `TB1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT TeacherID, ClassID, ClassStuID, s = [SUM],
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TeacherID ORDER BY ClassID)
  FROM dbo.TB1
)
SELECT TeacherID, ClassID, ClassStuID, 
  [SUM] = CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN s ELSE NULL END
FROM x
ORDER BY TeacherID, [SUM] DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can employ CTEs with ROW_NUMBER()OVER() to identify the first row of each TeacherID:

```
; with a as (
    select * from TB1
    union
    select * from TB2
)
, b as (
    select *, r=ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by a.TeacherID order by a.TeacherID, 
    a.ClassID, a.ClassStuID) from a
)
select b.TeacherID, b.ClassID, b.ClassStuID
, [SUM]=case b.r when 1 then b.[SUM] else null end
from b
order by b.TeacherID, b.r
go
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: ...ignoring TB2. How do you know we should do that?